# FWHM of different spectra and separation in fine structure

Tags: atomic-physics, spectroscopy, wavelength

I'm doing some research on spectroscopy and there are some phenomena I can't explain (only a second year physics student).

I took some spectra of neon in the 659.89529 nm and then of hydrogen at 656.279 nm to do some calibrations on the scale of my images.  I found that the spectra of neon had a full width at half maximum (FWHM) of 0.0140848685492 nm, which was much smaller than the one of hydrogen, i.e 0.0704243427458 nm.  Why is it that the width of neon is much smaller that that of hydrogen?

Second of all, I measured the fine structure on the yellow lines in mercury and found they were much more separated (in the order of nm) than the fine structure on the D-alpha line (on the order of $10^{-2}$ nm. Why is it that as atoms get heavier their fine structure speads?

Comment: Are you really able to measure these things down past the attometer scales?

Comment: No, I am sorry. The FMHW only have about 2 significant figures

Comment: I work in Gamma spectroscopy, not optical. However, I wonder whether it makes sense to say that the FWHM of the hydrogen line is larger because it's a higher intensity? This would result in a wider line? The second question I do not have an answer to.

Comment: Were the sources at the same Intensity?  You can always have power broadening which is when your line broadens as power increases. And then I may be mistaken, but fine structure scales as $E_n$ and E would be proportional to mass, so that would explain that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all I would recommend you to plot your spectra as a function of energy rather than wavelength. This is because wavelength is a reciprocal scale which makes it difficult to compare linewidths and, moreover, if you do spectroscopy you are mostly interested in energy differences anyway.

Now your linewidths. Typically the dominant broadening effect under these conditions (i.e. gas cell) is the Doppler effect which depends on the speed of your particles and the wavelength. The relative speed of the particles depends on the temperature and mass of the particles. Assuming that both arc lamps operate at similar temperatures the ratio of the velocities is given by

$\frac{v_\text{H}}{v_\text{Ne}}=\sqrt{\frac{m_\text{Ne}}{m_\text{H}}}\approx 4.5$,

To compare the linewidths of your measurements we use the relation

$\frac{\Delta f_\text{H}}{\Delta f_\text{Ne}}=\frac{\lambda_\text{Ne}^2}{\lambda_\text{H}^2}\frac{\Delta \lambda_\text{H}}{\Delta \lambda_\text{Ne}}\approx 5$.

In principle, the Doppler broadening also depends on the wavelength, however, since the wavelengths are so close here we may ignore the effect (it will give a ratio of 4.9 rather than 5). I assume that the slight difference is caused by different temperatures of the arc lamps and/or pressure broadening effects.

The fine structure of atoms scales as $(Z\alpha)^2$ where $Z$ is the nuclear charge and $\alpha\approx 1/137$ the fine-structure constant. That's why you expect a much bigger splitting in mercury than in hydrogen.